# How to draw/construct an Inductor node in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I am using Silverlight for some diagramming purposes. I need to have an Inductor node into my Diagram. How can I construct such a node in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

You are not very specific about what you mean about drawing and inductor node, but I assume you want to create some sort of electrical curcuit diagram.

You can use the classes in the [System.Windows.Shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes(v=VS.95).aspx) namespace to create drawings in Silverlight. Depending on your requirements you may want to place these shapes inside a [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(VS.95).aspx) panel.